# "Scholar of the first sin" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Since the release of the Scholar of the First Sin edition of Dark Souls 2, people have been asking questions about the functionalities of the game. For example [this one here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/215603/how-do-i-access-looking-glass-knight) is about accessing a boss, that normally, is easily managed. However the SotFS edition changes the way this works, making it effectively unanswerable by anyone that hasn't played the new edition.

For this reason, should we create a new tag? [dark-souls-2-sotfs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-souls-2-sotfs)

Additionally, what are people's thoughts on acronym tags? [dks1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dks1), [dks1-ptde](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dks1-ptde), [dks2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dks2), [dks2-sotfs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dks2-sotfs)

Comment: I would be okay with [tag:dark-souls-2-sotfs].

Comment: @Yuuki added :)

Comment: I don't think acronyms work. There are too many games that will have the same acronym, and we have enough characters for the full name (except [affordable-space-adventures](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10433/how-should-we-abbreviate-the-tag-for-affordable-space-adventures?cb=1)). The specific version can indeed by shortened, as you did in this example.